# strcmp forcing cmd error

Tags: c

I'm writing a program which the goal is to find strings which appear X or more times.

I have a list of words and my input is to give an int value, let's call it X, then the program finds the words that appear X times or more in the file, then, the output is HOW MANY WORDS appear X or more times in the file.
For a start I'm testing the function writting myself the words on the cmd and it's not working and I don't know why. The program just stops working and closes.

```
char *str_dup(const char *s){

    char *result = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    strcpy(result, s);
    return result;
}

int str_readline(FILE *f, char *s){

  int result = EOF;

  char *p = fgets(s, INT_MAX, f);

  if (p != NULL){


    result = (int) strlen(s);
    if (result > 0 && s[result-1] == '\n')
      s[--result] = '\0';
  }

  return result;
}

int strings_read(FILE *f, char **a){
    int result = 0;
    char line[10000];
    while(str_readline(f, line) !=EOF){
        a[result++] = str_dup(line);
    }
    return result;
}

int strings_get(char **a){
    return strings_read(stdin, a);
}

int howMany(char **a, int n, int x){
    int result = 0;
    int howMany = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(strcmp(a[i], a[i+1]) == 0){
            result++;
        }
        else if(strcmp(a[i], a[i+1]) > 0 || strcmp(a[i], a[i+1]) < 0){
            result = 0;
        }
        if(result >= x){
            howMany++;
        }

    }
    return howMany;
}

void test_howMany(void){
  char *a[1000];
  int x;
  scanf("%d", &x);
  int n;
  while((n = strings_get(a)) != 0){
    int z = howMany(a, n, x);
    printf("%d\n", z);
  }
}

int main(void){
    test_howMany();
    return 0;
}
```

The FIRST if means if the strings are equal, then add 1 value to result
The SECOND one means if they are not equal, result becomes 0 so that it can start looking again for how many equals we have the THIRD one means if the result is equal or above X then we have 1 more value on howMany, which is what I want at the end of the program.

What is wrong?

Comment: I guess this is the perfect time to learn how to use your debugger...

Comment: Please only show us code that at least compiles. And it should be somehow complete. What data goes into your function?

Comment: If `n` is the size of the array `a` the program goes out of bound when `i == n - 1`, because `a[i + 1]` is equal to `a[n]`.

Comment: If a word appears 10 times in the file, it doesn't have to be 10 times in a row...

Comment: It's there my TEST function.
The function strings_get is the one I use to write data in cmd, that will be used to the test.

For example: my input being
2
bla
bla
bla
hey

My output sould be 1

Comment: `else(strcmp(a[i], a[i+1]) > 0 || strcmp(a[i], a[i+1]) < 0)` isnt this missing an `if`?

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to. Do you want to calculate how often a word appears in a list? Which word? Or do you want to calculate how often all words appear in the list?

Comment: Yes, it's missing an if but that's not the problem, it is missing because I was making some changes to test the function, yet it won't work. Thanks btw for the observation

Comment: Pablo, I want to calculate how often a word appears X or more times in a list.
For example, for value X=2 with the words: abc, abc, abc, xyz the output is 1, because there was only one word which appeard X or more times

Comment: Gerhardh, it will be in a row because to make the process easier, I have another function that organizes the words, so that my function can work

Comment: 1) Your logic is wrong if that's what you want to do. Try developing an algorithm with pencil and paper and testing it on a few samples before coding it. 2) `a[i+1]` is probably indexing out of bounds when `i=n-1` but we don't know because you haven't shown your `strings_get(a)` function. 3) How do you know the crash isn't in `strings_get(a)`.

Comment: "Just stops working and closes" is not a problem statement. Is it running in a dedicated console which closes when it finishes, without you having a chance to read the output? Are you starting it in an existing terminal? Does it close that, or just end silently? This is all _necessary_ information that should be in your question already. Please show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe your runtime environment.

Comment: Do you expect us to guess as to the contents of your 'other' functions?  Do you expect us to guess as to the contents of your `main()` function?  Do you expect us to guess as to which header files your code is including?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and perhaps debug it.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the cs50.h header?

Comment: @Rafa Ok, but how should the algorithm know that you are looking for `"abc"` and not `"mickey mouse"`? You have function which only gets a list words, functions cannot read your mind. That was my point.

Comment: @Useless it closes without having a chance to read the output

Comment: @user3629249 I've updated, now there is the full code

Comment: @Pablo, like I said, for a start I'm testing the function howMany where I give the number X and where I write the words I want.
Because I use char *a[1000] in strings_get(a), and that 'a' is in int z = howMany(a, n, x);

Comment: `str_readline()`, `str_dup()` missing.

Comment: `test_ceia` doesn't appear in your code, so the above still doesn't compile. I guess that's supposed to be `test_howMany`? You still didn't describe how you're running this. Programs finishing (and the console window closing before you have a chance to read the output) is a very common issue for beginners on Windows. You need to do something to delay exit, or otherwise keep the console window around when the program is finished.

Comment: yep, sorry, updated

Comment: If `get_strings(a)` returns 10, that means you have 10 strings in `a[0]` to `a[9]` inclusive. All other values `a[10]` to `a[999]` are uninitialized. So when you do a `strcmp` and pass `a[10]` that's undefined behavior and could cause a crash. However, fixing that won't fix your logic error.

Comment: Guys it's working, thanks to @dbush, I changed the for statement in function howMany()  to for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) and put result=1 in the second if instead of result=0.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, and sorry for the poor post, it was my first but you helped me improve

Comment: @dbush pointed out three issues. Unless you fixed all three, it doesn't "work." It will run without crashing, but will produce incorrect output.

Comment: @MFisherKDX you're right, but I can handle the wrong output from here, thanks btw

Comment: regarding the function: `char *str_dup(const char *s)`,  the header file: `string.h`  exposes the function: `strdup()`, which make the function: `str_dup()`  unnecessary.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: @user3629249 hmm... my teacher said that C library didn't have that one, so I use this one that he gave my class

Comment: regarding: `char *p = fgets(s, INT_MAX, f);`  the macro `INT_MAX` is 2gig.  The posted code does not have a 2gig buffer named `s`. Infact, `s` is actually defined, in the calling function, as having a size of 10000.

Comment: from the MAN page for `strdup()`  "strdup():
           _SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
           _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
           || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
" so the header file `string.h` does have that function, just need to `#define` one of the macros listed.

Comment: the functions being used to read a line can be replaced by a single call to `getline()`, found in the header file: `stdio.h`  From the MAN page for `getline()`  "getline(), getdelim():
           Since glibc 2.10:
               _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700
           Before glibc 2.10:
               _GNU_SOURCE"   so do need to `#define` one of those macros

Comment: after using the available functions, ( `strdup()` and `getline()` ) most of the posted code can be eliminated.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 1000, 10000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: the posted code contains calls to the heap allocation function: `malloc()`, (which the code allows can be called up to ANY number of times, but fails to (before exiting) pass each of those allocated memory chunks to `free()`  the result is a massive memory leak.  The code should cleanup after itself, rather than leaving the mess for the OS to cleanup.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4):

There are three main problems here.

First, you're reading past the end of the array:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(strcmp(a[i], a[i+1]) == 0){
```

When `i` has a value of `n-1`, `a[i+1]` is actually `a[n]`, which is one element past the end of the array.  Reading past the end of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this caes manifests in a crash.  You need to change your loop to stop at `n-1`:

```
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
```

Second, your algorithm is only comparing adjacent words in this list.  For this to work, your list needs to be sorted, and your code isn't doing that.

Third, assuming you did sort the words, your counter starts at 0 when you find a new word.  So when you first find a word the count is 0, then when you find a second occurrence the count is 1, and so forth.  You need to start `result` at 1 when you find a new word.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! @dbush

First, your first is fully right, it worked !

Second, your second may be right but as I said  I am just testing the function howMany first

Third, your third is fully right too! thanks bro